# How to check if checkbox is checked php

Tags: php, checkbox

This is html code for my checkbox and button

```
<form> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="DNA" name="DNA" value="checkox_value">
     <button type="button" name="submit" onClick="search()" id="sim_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Start Simulation</button>
</form>
```

I want to check if checkbox is checked and if yes write the input to my file.
I tried using the isset function but it doesn't work any other suggestions?

```
if(isset($_POST["DNA"])) { 
        $input3 = "signal(f).";
        fwrite($handleStoryFile, $input3 . PHP_EOL); 
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a FORM surrounding the elements?

Comment: yes just didn't include it here

Comment: can you include `function search`'s code, generally if a checkbox is not checked then it won't be sent up, if your js is sending it up always then you may need to tweak your post payload

Comment: or perhaps just change to `if (!empty($_POST["DNA"])) {`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" id="DNA" name="DNA" value="checkox_value">
 <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sim_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Start Simulation</button>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["DNA"])) { 
        echo 'test';
   } 
?>
</body>
</html>
```